# Difference in SQL syntax for enabling a constraint (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there any difference between these two statements below?

```
ALTER TABLE [table_name] CHECK CONSTRAINT [constraint_name]
```

and

```
ALTER TABLE [table_name] WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT [constraint_name]
```

Answer (score 1):

From [Alter Table documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx):

**WITH CHECK | WITH NOCHECK:**

Specifies whether the data in the table is or is not validated against a newly added or re-enabled FOREIGN KEY or CHECK constraint. If not specified, WITH CHECK is assumed.

So, since the default is to do it "WITH CHECK", there is no difference at all.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Considering i'm adding a brand new constraint for some table, your statement is correct. However, if that constraint already exists, the expected behavior is the same as @dex-star has posted below.

Answer (score -1):

The WITH CHECK clause will check any existing data and fail if there is data that doesn't meet the constraint.  Without the WITH CHECK clause, the constraint will only apply to new data added to the table.

If the table has no data in it, then the statements are functionally equivalent.

Here is the documentation for the ALTER TABLE command in question:
    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx

It's a rather lengthy page, so I'll quote from it:

> WITH CHECK | WITH NOCHECK
>     Specifies whether the data in the table is or is not validated against a newly added or re-enabled
>     FOREIGN KEY or CHECK constraint. If not specified, WITH CHECK is assumed for new constraints,
>  
>     and WITH NOCHECK is assumed for re-enabled constraints.

It goes on to give this advice:

> If you do not want to verify new CHECK or FOREIGN KEY constraints against existing data, use WITH
>   NOCHECK. We do not recommend doing this, except in rare cases. The new constraint will be 
>   evaluated in all later data updates. Any constraint violations that are suppressed by WITH NOCHECK 
>   when the constraint is added may cause future updates to fail if they update rows with data that 
>   does not comply with the constraint.

Comment: Please provide references to what you're claiming, e.g. a link to the documentation page.

Comment: I made a POC for myself and realized the behavior matches this answer, although there is no link to the documentation page.

Comment: I posted a link to the proper documentation and cited the section that's relevant.  1,000 Apologies for not providing a reference originally.  This is my first contribution to this site.  I understand the need for a source though.